# How to test the program on a slow Internet connection?

Tags: c#, testing

How to programmatically you can slow down access to the internet?

Comment: Check this question, it's probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031157/mimic-slowness-of-web-server-on-local-computer

Comment: mode details! You want to slow internet for your app or the whole PC? or what ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by VDesmedT, Netlimiter is a great tool. I used it some years ago to not to claim our full corporate internet connection during working hours while downloading big ISO's.

But I would suggest a dedicated box that was build exactly for that purpose, like this one.

http://wanem.sourceforge.net/

It is a standalone appliance (or virtual machine) where you can simulate a WAN line with many aspects like:

- Bandwith
- Package Loss
- Data Corruption
- Different Up/Download speeds

There are more tools like that out there (search `WAN emulator` at your favorite search engine) but that one looks promissing, even if I never used it before but only a similar, commercial appliance.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of bandwith limiter on the Net, [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/) is a very good at this.

Comment: Netlimiter does not work. None of the settings have any effect. Look elsewhere.